# Can I deploy my Content on drupal using scripts?

Tags: commerce, drush

If suppose I have a drupal application in Github and I have automated drupal installation using chef. Now I want to deploy that application content such that i can see it on my content page. 
I am unable to put php and drupal tags due to reputation.

Comment: you can create nodes programmatically (like blog posts or basic pages). Is that what you're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to automate your deploys of content, just like you automate your code deploys, you'll probably want to look into the [migrate module](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate).  This model is best for sites where the content is managed by a content-generation team; it is less applicable for sites that have a lot of user-generated content.  This is a viable model that some people use, though, and is a very compelling workflow if your use-case supports it. One good extant site that uses this technique and has a public GitHub repository is [Gizra's Negawatt](https://github.com/Gizra/negawatt-live).